# Problems with Windows 8.1 install of Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, windows

I have replaced my Arduino, thinking it would solve the problem, but I still get it. Whenever I try to upload code, I get the error messages programmer is not responding and not in sync. Then I heard Arduino had drivers required. But my Windows 8.1 didn't recognize Arduino Uno. It was put in the other devices area as an unknown device in the device manager. The update driver button is greyed out. I get the message:

> The drivers for this device are not installed (code 28). There are no
>   compatible drivers for this device. To find a driver for this device,
>   click update driver.

That's the greyed out button… When I look at driver details, it says 'No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device.' For the not in sync/programmer not responding error, I've tried restarting the board before uploading, restarting whilst uploading, you say it, I've done it. How can I fix this so I can finally follow my dream to be an engineer/programmer?

Comment: Have you tried, maybe, *installing* the drivers...?

Comment: Sorry but from what I read it said that windows should automatically recognise arduino UNO. But thanks, I'll download the drivers

Comment: Windows 10 can. All other versions require the Arduino CDC/ACM drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Getting started with a new toolchain can be quite a challenge…

I'm not a Windows guy, but it looks like there **are** drivers that need to  be installed to get things working with the Arduino. I'm guessing that what is going on here is that Windows is looking locally for drivers and not finding them (or any indication that drivers are needed). I think the button was grayed out because it couldn't help – not because help wasn't needed.

Here are a few sources that I found by searching on:

> arduino driver windows 8.1

1. [[SOLVED] Arduino drivers for Windows 8.1 64bit](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=205837.0)
2. [Windows 8.1 (64bit) USB-serial driver for Arduino?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/windows-81-64bit-usb-serial-driver-for-arduino/418f4de7-1361-4f98-ace6-4f6c0c44340b?db=5&auth=1)
3. [Installing the Arduino IDE – Windows 8.1 & 10](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/3727)
4. [Install Arduino Drivers on Windows 8](http://mytechblog.com/tutorials/arduino/install-arduino-drivers-on-windows-8/)

While we're at it, it is worth mentioning that "out of sync" error message from avrdude are very common. A bit of searching here will find you some good resources on solving them as well – deal with the drivers first, then see if errors persist.

Comment: the IDE comes automatically with the drivers, how do I install them? Everyone online says 'click update driver and select those drivers' but , as you know, my update driver button is greyed out.